# Thread loop executes once in android

Tags: android, multithreading, bluetooth

im making an app that should send a message after certain amount of time via bluetooth.

The thread works fine when i use "Log" but when i use the write function of bluetooth, it seems to executes the loop when the app wants.

Hope somebody can help me:

```
    public class AsyncWrite extends Thread {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
    try {this.sleep(250);} catch (Exception E) {}
    //Log.e(TAG,"Test run");
    mConnectedThread.write(A);
        }
    }
}
```

I've already try using asynctask executors and handlers, the result it's the same.

Comment: What´s the content of mConnectedThread.write() method? it seems that the second time it throws an exception or it gets blocked

Comment: I've already fix it, it seem's that when you have only one Bluetooth thread for Writing and Reading, it's collapses.

I've recommend to create two separates threads and synchronize for avoid crashes